How to stop “leave on time sensitive notifications from” notifications?
My iPhone and MacBook are constantly adding to my notifications:

Leave on Time Sensitive notifications from ___? This allows ___ to deliver important notifications immediately.
[Turn Off] [Leave On]

I have never understood or wanted this question. I have always clicked [Leave On], but it never stops asking. I have attempted to disable every Siri AI option in Syst Prefs. If I did not want to receive a notification, I would disable said notification, which is easy to do. How do I disable this instead?
